# How to mount raw HDD image on Windows?

Tags: disk-image

I tried [OSFMount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) on a image of a SD card, but it doesn't detect its filesystem. Seems for me it requires a partition image, not drive image. Any other way?

Comment: Your question is not written as a software recommendation. Can you [edit] it and make it one. You'll also need to describe what a *raw HDD image* is - what was it made with? The question also looks surprisingly like http://superuser.com/questions/835296/windows-creating-a-virtual-drive-out-of-a-physical-partition; Smit Johnth is a bad pseudonym ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen raw image = bytewise copy.

Comment: John: "How to" = "off-topic" here. Reading between the lines, you're looking for some software to mount raw HDD images. I'd suggest you to [edit] and re-phrase your question accordingly (it already attracted several votes to be closed as off-topic/too broad). While doing so, please check [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – you e.g. can't complain "Win7 only :(" if you didn't specify what Windows version you're using ;)

Comment: Have you tried Gnu/Linux. This sort of thing is easy using the Unixes. To run Gnu/Linux in Microsoft's windows, you will need VirtualBox (or similar).

Comment: *You've earned the "Notable Question" badge (Question with 2,500 views) for a closed question.*

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a raw image into a VHD basically it just needs some extra headers.

Microsoft created a tool called vhdtool.exe which can convert the raw image.  A technet post here lists all the tools for hyper-v http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/121.hyper-v-tools.aspx.

Please note as Microsoft has terminated technet things are getting hard to find.

As an alternative you can use [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and its VBoxManage tool to convert a raw disk dump into a VHD-file:

```
VBoxManage.exe convertdd disk.raw disk.vhd --format VHD
```

You can then mount the VHD (windows 7 and above only though)

To do this:

- Open Computer Management (In admin tools control panel)
- Click Disk Management
- Click Action -> Mount VHD (If greyed out click on the list of drives)

**EDIT**

**Make sure you work on a copy of the image file as the vhdtool.exe tool writes directly to the file specified!!**

**Also you will need to rename the file to .vhd manually after**

Comment: "windows 7 and above only" :(